# Getting error trying to create stored procedure using type table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Trying to create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Students   
    @List StudentList READONLY,    
    @AdmissionId VARCHAR(max) 
AS
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO RcordsTable (StudentId, RollNumber, AdmissionId)
    VALUES(@List.StudentId, @List.RollNumber, @AdmissionId)
END
```

Where `List` is type valued table which is already created in the database with 3 columns `StudentList`, `RollNumber` and `Id`.

When I try to create this procedure in SQL Server 2008, I am getting following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable @List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working in **T-SQL** - not in C# here! The `@List` parameter needs to be treated like a T-SQL table variable - not like a C# object....

So you need to use T-SQL style statements - like `SELECT` from the table-valued parameter `@List` - not C# style "dot-notation" (like when accessing the fields of a .NET object):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Students   
    @List StudentList READONLY,    
    @AdmissionId VARCHAR(max) 
AS
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO RcordsTable (StudentId, RollNumber, AdmissionId)
        SELECT
            StudentId, RollNumber, @AdmissionId
        FROM @List
END
```

Side note: why is an `AdmissionId` defined as a `Varchar(max)` type?? `Id` sounds numeric to me --> use an appropriate numeric type. And if it's not numeric - then you should define and use a **sensible length** for the `VARCHAR` - don't just get overly lazy and use `VARCHAR(MAX)` for everything - it's not a good idea!

Read this excellent article for more details on that topic: [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/)